# Reasoning about properties of subtypes

Tags: alloy

I find myself often faced with something like the following:

```
sig Property {}

abstract sig Unit {
  property: some Property
}


sig Hardware, Software, Services extends Unit {}

fact  {
  no Hardware.property & Software.property
  no Hardware.property & Services.property
  no Software.property & Services.property
}
```

Namely, I have an abstract signature which declares an attribute, and some number of subtypes extending that signature. I want to ensure that there's no overlap in the attribute `property` between the subtypes.

Two instances of `Hardware` would be allowed to have shared `property` values, but `Hardware` and `Software` instances should never be allowed to have a common property.

I'd really rather not have to write the `fact` like that. If I add a fourth kind of `Unit`, I could easily mess up the fact.

This feels like I'd need to be able to introspect the types, but I don't know of any facilities to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe not be the most elegant solution but you could define a property subtype for each unit subtype.

That way, you won't need to manually write the cross-product, making it less error-prone :-).

```
abstract sig Property {}

abstract sig Unit {
  property: some Property
}

sig Hardware, Software, Services extends Unit {}
sig PropHard , PropSoft, PropServ extends Property{}

fact {
    Hardware.property in PropHard
    Software.property in PropSoft
    Services.property in PropServ
}
```

Comment: I’ve used approaches like that in the past. It was also suggested that I could use `disj [Hardware.property, Software.property, Services.property]` So I have a few options, but all of them require me “remembering” to do something should I add a new subtype of `Unit`

Comment: If this model is meant to be changed a lot and to be used over a long period of time, you can always think of a solution to generate those additional facts automatically :-).